# How to get a random list of 10 numbers from 1 to 10 without repeating the members of the list

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting, arraylist

I'm trying to write a method that gets a list of numbers from 1 to 10 where there will be no duplicates. Also the member must not be zero.
However, after many attempts I failed to solve the problem, this is my code:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> dobijNiz() {
        int min = 1;
        int max = 10;
        ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            int broj = random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

            lista.add(broj);   
        }
        System.out.println(lista);
        return lista;
    }
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 6, 10, 8, 2, 7, 9]
```

I forgot to say that Collections.shuffle doesn't work

Comment: Program to the `List` interface (instead of specifying `ArrayList` everywhere). `List<Integer> lista = IntStream.range(min, max).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());` and then `Collections.shuffle(lista, ThreadLocalRandom.current());`

Comment: There is a problem in the question. If you need 10 random numbers and list size is 10, then it is always has to be numbers between 1 to 10 only.

Assuming you are expecting 5 random from 1 to 10, then this is how it would be.

You should also need to have a check of max-min is greater than count to ensure it does to go infinite loop :) 

[![Working Example][1]][1]



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOLmw.gif

Answer (score 2):

Add all possible numbers into the ArrayList, then use `Collections.shuffle` to shuffle the list.

```
int min = 1;
int max = 10;
ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    lista.add(i);   
}
Collections.shuffle(lista);
```